# How to upload a resource programatically in a custom CKAN plugin?

Tags: ckan

I am developing a CKAN plugin extension that needs to programatically create a new dataset and then add a new resource (file) to it. Not sure how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
PK

Answer (score 0):

Plugins can create resources by calling the [`resource_create()` action function](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api.html#ckan.logic.action.create.resource_create). Extensions call action functions via the [plugins toolkit's `get_action()` function](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugins-toolkit.html#ckan.plugins.toolkit.get_action). (See the new [writing extensions documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/index.html)).

But as far as I know plugins cannot upload files to CKAN via the plugin interfaces or plugins toolkit. To do that you would have to use the [FileStore API](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/filestore.html#filestore-api). [Ckanclient](https://github.com/okfn/ckanclient) contains some [Python code for uploading resources to CKAN via the API](https://github.com/okfn/ckanclient). Maybe your extension can call ckanclient to do the uploading?

Comment: I was able to upload a file using the storage controller that is part of the core. But that may not be a good way to do it as I am accessing the core directly. I looked at the Ckanclient code which does the upload through http call. I thought that is not probably the right way to do it when my extension code and ckan core code running on the same server. Recently I came to know about the ckanapi extension which seems to allow accessing the action API and make those api calls locally (no http). Not sure though if it supports file upload.

Comment: [ckanapi](https://github.com/open-data/ckanapi) doesn't support file uploading as far as I know. I would recommend uploading files over the API using ckanclient, even if your code is running on the same server as your CKAN instance, as far as I know there isn't any other supported way to do it. You're right that accessing the storage controller directly isn't a good idea - in a new CKAN release the storage controller may change and your code will break.